When I go to logout the site lists websites I have not signed up for or visited
When I went to logout of one of the stackexchange sites the site popped up a message that said, "Do you want to logout of other sites on this device?"

I've only joined half of the sites listed.
In fact, right after this I attempted to go to one of them I've never visited and I attempted to login. It immediately granted me 100+ points for joining.
Is this a bug or is something else going on? Tell me what I need to do

Those look like all of the top-level domains for the SE network. I would expect that it means the logout will apply to all of these (if applicable) and any other accounts on a subdomain.
I don’t think it’s a bug, exactly; it’s just listing everything that the “logout” action could apply to, whether or not it does in your case. I’d bet that’s easier than having it look up which accounts you have & such.

Particularly the stackexchange.com domain, because it includes 100+ SE sites
